# Focus nearest window to left/right/down/up using wmutils

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

I am trying to focus the nearest window left/right/down/up of the current window using wmutils[1] and shell scripting. The plan is to list all window ID and offset and find the closest window to the focused window in a given direction. The offset in the x direction is the pixels between the left side of the screen and the left border of the window.

Here I am using `pfw` to get the window ID of the current window. Then I use `lsw` to list all windows and pipe into `sed` to remove the current window ID from the list. Lastly I find the current windows x offset with `wattr x $cur` (I am only using the x offset because solving down/up should be trivial once I get left/right done).

```
cur=`pfw`
rcw=`lsw | sed '/'$cur'/d'`
curoff=`wattr x $cur`
```

Then I print the window ID and x offset of every other window.

```
for i in $rcw
do
        wattr ix $i
done
```

The output looks like this with the window ID in the first field and x offset in second:

```
0x00c00005 152
0x01000015 0
0x01800001 2
0x01a00005 67
```

Now I need to subtract the x offset of the current window from the x offset of every other window to find the closest one in the x direction (left or right). So I piped the output to `awk`:

```
awk '
{ dis = $2 - '$curoff' }
{ print $1 , dis }
'
```

Which prints the window ID and the distance between the focused window and the the other windows. So the windows to the left have negative distance and windows to right are positive. Now to figure out the closest window to the left I have to find the largest negative number in the output. And for the closest window to the right I have to find the smallest positive number. Here is an example of the output:

```
0x01000015 -166
0x01600005 514
0x01800001 -164
```

I tried finding the minimum but that doesn't work since we have negative and positive numbers. Another idea could be to find the negative number closest to 0 for left and the positive number closest to 0 for right. Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: Well presented and an interesting problem, and you've got enough code that this qualifies as a programming problem (IMHO). What is the context of your problem, a personal function on you ultra fast workstation OR you're building a tool that will be incorporated into a major software release targeted at millions of users on a small embeded linux with a cust version of busybox? (--;? . Easist would be to scan list per neg/pos and use `sort`, picking off the top or bottom of the list as required. Good luck.

Comment: I will bind this script to a keybind to cycle between windows. It will be run fairly often so it should be efficient.

Comment: please update the question with a) output from `typeset -p cur rcw curoff` and 2) the (correct) expected output corresponding to these 3 variables and the set of `wattr -ix` output; also update that 2nd set of id/offsets (3 rows showing negative offsets) to insure they match your other inputs (ie, the `wattr -ix` output shows 4 rows but only 3 rows show in the id/offsets table; and the id's don't match between the `wattr -ix` output and the id/offsets table)

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work with any POSIX `awk` and also skip the current window (what you currently do with `sed`):

```
awk -v cur="$cur" -v curoff="$curoff" -v min=-1 '
  {dis = $2 - curoff; dis = dis < 0 ? -dis : dis}
  $1 != cur && (min == -1 || dis < min) {min = dis; id = $1}
  END {print "ID: " id " (offset " min ")"}
'
```

3 variables are defined on the command line with the `-v` option: `cur`, `curoff` and `min`, initialized to -1. The first line of the script stores the distance in variable `dis` and if it is negative, takes its opposite. The second updates `min` and `id` whenever we did not process any window yet (`min == -1`) or the distance is less than all previously encountered (`dis < min`), and it is not the current window (`$1 != cur`). The last line prints the result.

For the other parts I suggest to simplify a bit with `xargs`:

```
cur=$(pfw); curoff=$(wattr x "$cur")
lsw | xargs -n1 wattr ix | awk -v cur="$cur" -v curoff="$curoff" -v min=-1 '
  {dis = $2 - curoff; dis = dis < 0 ? -dis : dis}
  $1 != cur && (min == -1 || dis < min) {min = dis; id = $1}
  END {print "ID: " id " (offset " min ")"}
'
```